# ECMA-48 and ANSI X3.64 Implementation

Tags: tmux, gnu-screen, ansi-escape

I'm currently developing a console application with a text-based user interface, in python, which is meant to be an open-source, UNIX alternative for a series of industry standard software and to minimize, in my opinion, the hardware/software requirements for a software of such scale.

**However, I do not prefer using curses/ncurses in order to understand the principles of how such libraries work and implement them for my own purposes.** For that I've been - let's say - experimenting with ANSI Escape Sequences, for a while.

At some point, I've felt the need that I should split (or to describe in UNIX terminology, multiplex) my terminal into sessions, windows or panes as in GNU Screen or tmux. However, for the reasons I mentioned above, instead of using them in my project I tried to discover their source to get inspired. But the truth is that they both require an extensive knowledge of C, at least for me at this point, and searching through the source codes is exhaustive.

I've recenlty found out that GNU Screen documentation refers to ECMA 48 and ANSI X3.64.

**Screen User's Manual**

> Each virtual terminal provides the functions of the DEC VT100 terminal
>   and, in addition, several control functions from the ISO 6429 (ECMA
>   48, ANSI X3.64) and ISO 2022 standards (e.g. insert/delete line and
>   support for multiple character sets). There is a scrollback history
>   buffer for each virtual terminal and a copy-and-paste mechanism that
>   allows the user to move text regions between windows.

I also checked ECMA 48 and ANSI X3.64 for what I want to achieve, couldn't find a clue.

My questions actually arise at this point.

1. How can I find out which coded character sets in those standards are implemented? For example in §8.3.123 of ECMA 48 refers to DEVICE COMPONENT SELECT MODE, which I could found no signs of implementation or use thereof.
2. What is the working principle of Screen or tmux in creating a window and pane? What kind of path do they follow for creating windows or panes.

The time I've spent for the second question is quite a lot, and took me nowhere. I thought they may be sweeping the whole screen, drawing borders, delimiting lines or columns with coded characters each time there needs to be an update (resizing, creating a new pane etc.). I considered this option may be a basic but frustrating solution. And I could not be sure that screen or tmux works in that way. But I am pretty sure that I am missing a critical point here.

Any help, opinion or recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: Curses: good, stable, easy to use, portable across an extemely wide range of platforms and devices.  Escape codes: a really, really Bad Idea.

Comment: @paulsm4, thanks for the advice. I think that is what I'm going to favor for, unless I could find a solution

Comment: Wow - I thought you'd either ignore me or argue with me.  Thank you :)  Anyway, if you're not already familiar with them, these links might help: [Curses Programming with Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html), or [Curses Programming with Python2](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html) (depending on which Python you prefer).

Comment: Well, that would be rude and arrogant of someone who seeks for "recommendations" :). Thanks again.